# I am trying to loop through an array of objects and populate them to a table

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Question 1 - So I am trying to do just a simple loop through my json array and create a new row for each of the objects in the array. For some reason I can't figure out, it is only printing the last object of the array to the DOM. So I know I have everything connected right, I just don't know why only the one object is showing up.

I know there are other posts similiar to this all over the internet, I just am having trouble figuring out my exact problem.

Question 2 - I get the error

> "cannot read property insertRow of undefined"

in the console if I try to put the initial `var row = table.insertRow(-1);` inside my function, but I don't get the error if it's outside my function. I thought if it was inside the GenerateTable() then my function would be still be able to access it?

```js
var table_data = [{
    first_name: 'Zoe',
    last_name: 'Heriot',
    home: 'Space Station W3'
}, {
    first_name: 'Jo',
    last_name: 'Grant',
    home: 'Earth'
}, {
    first_name: 'Clara',
    last_name: 'Oswald',
    home: 'Earth'
}, {
    first_name: 'Adric',
    last_name: null,
    home: 'Alzarius'
}, {
    first_name: 'Susan',
    last_name: 'Foreman',
    home: 'Gallifrey'
}];


var row = table.insertRow(-1);

function GenerateTable() {

    var table = document.getElementById('table')[1];
    for (var i = 0; i <= table_data.length; i++) {

        var firstName = table_data[i].first_name;
        var lastName = table_data[i].last_name;
        var home = table_data[i].home;

        row.innerHTML = `
  <td>${firstName}</td>
  <td>${lastName}</td>
  <td>${home}</td>
`;
    };
};

if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" :
    document.readyState !== "loading") {
    GenerateTable();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', GenerateTable);
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Home</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are inserting only a single row into the table. You need to do that inside the loop. You even say so at the start of the question, but your code doesn't reflect that at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

You can't access a variable before you define it. The first line of your script does this, which is why you get the error:

```
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
```

`table` isn't defined until inside the function, so you can't use it until you've told javascript what it is. Additionally you want to add a row for each trip through the loop, so you need to put the `insertRow()` call inside the loop where it will add a row each time.

Also, i the loop you want to stop when `i < table_data.length` not `<=` otherwise it will throw an error on the last trip through.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var table_data =[{ first_name : 'Zoe',
                 last_name : 'Heriot',
                 home : 'Space Station W3'},
                 { first_name : 'Jo',
                 last_name : 'Grant',
                 home : 'Earth'},
               { first_name : 'Clara',
                 last_name : 'Oswald',
                 home : 'Earth'},
               { first_name : 'Adric',
                 last_name : null,
                 home : 'Alzarius'},
               { first_name : 'Susan',
                 last_name : 'Foreman',
                 home : 'Gallifrey'} ];

function GenerateTable(){
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    for (var i=0; i < table_data.length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);

        var firstName = table_data[i].first_name;
        var lastName = table_data[i].last_name;
        var home = table_data[i].home;

        row.innerHTML = `
        <td>${firstName}</td>
        <td>${lastName}</td>
        <td>${home}</td>
        `;
    };
};
GenerateTable()
```

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #ccdced;
    }
 td, th {
  padding:.5em
  }
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Home</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ahhh! That makes so much sense, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

```
row.innerHTML = `
  <td>${firstName}</td>
  <td>${lastName}</td>
  <td>${home}</td>
`;
```

Is saying "remove everything in `row.innerHTML` and replace with `<td>$...`. And since the `row` value never change, you'll always write to the same row.

**Question 2:**

Have you tried to put `table.insertRow()` after the `table` var definition and remove the `[1]`? Like:

```
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
```

You can read more about `insertRow` and how it can be used at [Mozilla Developer pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow).